# does Android application come with sqlite databse created when an application is released?

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I am working on some android application. I have two related questions about SQLite database in android.

1) I have got a bunch of SQL queries to create database tables in my SQLiteOpenHelper class. The queries are executed in onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) method. Are the database and database tables re-created each time I run my application, using my cellphone? or Should I do something else to create database and tables at once if they don't exist?

2) When I release my application, like to Playstore, do I remove all the SQL queries and include the created database file in my application folder so that users can download the database along with the application? or should I leave the SQL queries to create database and tables so that users download my application and when they run it, the queries are executed and create the database?

Sorry guys for asking two questions at a time, but I believe they are quite related.

Thanks!

Comment: The database that I meant in the question is Local database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)Once you have changed your database structure something like adding columns or  modify existing table,

You should increase your database version number. Then only your changes will be applied.

```
 public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
```

For more info refer this link.
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

2) You can't remove all the SQL queries and include the created database file in your application. Because the table only created when the user runs the application. And it is created only once by calling the database initialization method. Only the database is updated if you increase the database version number.

Comment: thanks for quick response um what about question 2 please?

Comment: Oh I see so I should keep all the SQL queries to create the database and tables in my application source code so that when users run the app, it can create tables. Is it right? thanks for quick response by the way

Comment: Yes, it will create tables when they run.

Comment: sorry for bothering but how can I accept your answer?